# Wordpress: How to dynamically post a html code to index using php

Tags: php, wordpress

can you teach me how to make my plain html code into a dynamic post using wordpress, thank you

**its like a custom post i think**

**This is the sample html content**

```
   <div class="worksido col-sm-10  col-centered wow fadeInUp ">
          <a href="#">
            <img id="whatid" class="img-responsive col-centered" src="img/mock-04.png">
           </a>
                  <h5> Video Editing - for curated beauty</h5>
                  <h5 class="lasth5">Afredo</h5>
          </div>
```

Comment: Did you mean you want to add this code in wordpress post content area ?

Comment: @Jalpa everytime i have a new project, thats the code for the img, title and name, i want to have a function for that so everytime i have a new project ill post it

Comment: You mean, everytime when you post a new post, it should automatically get added ?

Comment: yah and thats the format, it will automatically add another code like that

Comment: @AlfredDizon Please try as per my answer and let me know if any change.

Comment: @AlfredDizon Didn't get you what you want exactly ?

Comment: @Jalpa not like your code below. its like this everytime i have a new project, i want to have a post functionality that will post my html code  but change the value of it, its like this  **new img, new title, new name** its like posting a blog post,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin for get content in post. Please try below plugin.

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-for-posts/
```

Comment: @AlfredDizon Didn't get you what you want ? for 'btw how can i post'.

Comment: not like your code below. its like this everytime i have a new project, i want to have a post functionality that will post my html code but change the value of it, its like this new img, new title, new name its like posting a blog post,

Comment: @AlfredDizon please try above please.

Comment: sorry its like a custom post i think :(

Comment: @AlfredDizon No, not its for custom post you need to add code in plugin setting and use short code in post content.